# Why is my while not loop with two conditions only using the first condition and ignoring the second condition?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to set up a while not loop that uses two conditions with 'or'. Essentially, I am asking for input from user on a loan type, and if one of the two loans is not entered, it prints that it is not a valid loan type and asks for the input again. However, my code is only working for the first condition and the second is being ignored.

Here is my code below:

```
loan = input('Enter the type of mortgage loan for the purchase of this property: \n').lower() #Asks for the type of mortgage loan
while not loan == 'fha' or loan == 'conventional': #Checks if input is fha or conventional, if not asks for input again
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid loan type.")
    loan = input('Enter the type of mortgage loan for the purchase of this property: \n').lower()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A less confusing alternative would be:

```py
loan = input('Enter the type of mortgage loan for the purchase of this property: \n').lower() #Asks for the type of mortgage loan
while loan not in ("fha", "conventional"):
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid loan type.")
    loan = input('Enter the type of mortgage loan for the purchase of this property: \n').lower()
```

Comment: That worked exactly how I wanted it to! Thanks a lot I was wondering how to set it up like that to check if the input is in a list/tuple

Comment: you can also put it inside a variable such as ```loan_types = ("fha","conventional")```. Another option is using list ```loan_types=["fha","conventional"]``` for mutability.